# Pandas sum every value over certain month range every year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to sum data from January through June every year. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date       Value
1980-01-01 2
1980-02-01 3
1980-03-01 3
1980-04-01 2
1980-05-01 3
1980-06-01 3
```

I would like there to then be a new column that stores the value of the data as `Sum` for every 6 month interval each year such that the sum would = 16 for this example. I tried using a combination of `df.groupby()` and `df.sum()` but couldn't quite figure it out.

Expected output would look something like this:

```
Date       Value   Sum
1980-01-01 2       16
1980-02-01 3
1980-03-01 3
1980-04-01 2
1980-05-01 3
1980-06-01 3
```

Comment: can you show your expected output?

Comment: I edited the question for the expected output.

Comment: You you have different months/years in your data?

Comment: I have every month from 1980-present

Comment: something like `df.loc[df["Date"].dt.month.le(6)].groupby(df["Date"].dt.year)["Value"].transform('sum')` ?

Comment: That works. How would I change it so it could be any 6 month time frame? For example, like September through February?

Comment: `How would I change it so...` - use `isin` instead of `le` and specify a sequence of integers.

Comment: agreed, it's hard to say as you'll need to use boolean filtering to split out your dataframe so you don't overwrite values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
idx = pd.Series(pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=100, freq='MS'),name='date')
df = pd.DataFrame(range(len(idx)), index=idx,columns=['A'])
```

Filter then [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#resampling).

```
>>> sums = df.loc[df.index.month.isin([1,2,3,4,5,6])].resample('YS').sum()
>>> sums['A'].values
array([ 15,  87, 159, 231, 303, 375, 447, 519, 390], dtype=int64)
>>> sums
              A
date           
2018-01-01   15
2019-01-01   87
2020-01-01  159
2021-01-01  231
2022-01-01  303
2023-01-01  375
2024-01-01  447
2025-01-01  519
2026-01-01  390
>>>
```

---

I assumed that `date` was the index in your example. If it is a column change you need to use the [`dt` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors) in the filter and specify the column name in `resample`.

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'date':idx,'A':range(len(idx))})
>>> sums = dfa.loc[dfa.date.dt.month.isin([1,2,3,4,5,6])].resample('YS',on='date').sum()
>>> sums['A'].values
array([ 15,  87, 159, 231, 303, 375, 447, 519, 390], dtype=int64)
```

You could also resample/aggregate on a six month frequency and just take every other result - it seems to work even if months are missing from the Series.

```
>>> dfq = dfa.loc[::2]
>>> dfq.head()
        date  A
0 2018-01-01  0
2 2018-03-01  2
4 2018-05-01  4
6 2018-07-01  6
8 2018-09-01  8
>>> dfc = dfq.resample('6MS', on='date').sum()
>>> dfc.loc[::2].head()
              A
date           
2018-01-01    6
2019-01-01   42
2020-01-01   78
2021-01-01  114
2022-01-01  150
```

---

If the DataFrame only contains the first six months of each year then you don't need to filter. Just resample.

```
>>> dfb = dfa.loc[dfa.date.dt.month.isin([1,2,3,4,5,6])]
>>> dfb.resample('YS',on='date').sum().head()
              A
date           
2018-01-01   15
2019-01-01   87
2020-01-01  159
2021-01-01  231
2022-01-01  303
>>>
```

Comment: I get this error: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'month'

Comment: If it makes any difference I edited my dataframe to only contain data from the first 6 months of every year. So Jan-June of 1980, then Jan-June of 1981, etc. How would I then go about summing the data every 6 months, but not making it a cumulative sum over all of the years?

Comment: @EliTurasky - Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. Please don't continually morph questions.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you for this.