# Six Monthly returns from may to October

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance

I want to Compute semi-annual (six-monthly) returns by compounding monthly returns over six-monthly periods from May-October

I just want to extract the Dataframe of may to October for all the years.

like the first year, I will extract may - October, same with other subsequent years

```
def month_year_iter( start_month, start_year, end_month, end_year ):
    ym_start= 12*start_year + start_month - 1
    ym_end= 12*end_year + end_month - 1
    for ym in range( ym_start, ym_end ):
        y, m = divmod( ym, 12 )
        yield y, m+1

start = dt.datetime(1970, 12, 1)
end = dt.datetime(2018, 12, 1)
df = web.get_data_yahoo("^GSPC", start, end)

df.head(5)

     Date    High         Low       Open       Close      Volume    Adj Close

1970-12-01  88.610001   86.110001   87.199997  87.470001  20170000  87.470001
1970-12-02  88.830002   86.720001   87.470001  88.480003  17960000  88.480003
1970-12-03  89.870003   88.110001   88.480003  88.900002  20480000  88.900002
1970-12-04  89.889999   88.120003   88.900002  89.459999  15980000  89.459999
1970-12-07  90.389999   88.760002   89.459999  89.940002  15530000  89.940002

df.tail(5)

    Date    High          Low       Open       Close      Volume    Adj Close

2018-11-26  88.610001   86.110001   87.199997  87.470001  20170000  87.470001
2018-11-27  88.830002   86.720001   87.470001  88.480003  17960000  88.480003
2018-11-28  89.870003   88.110001   88.480003  88.900002  20480000  88.900002
2018-11-29  89.889999   88.120003   88.900002  89.459999  15980000  89.459999
2018-11-30  90.389999   88.760002   89.459999  89.940002  15530000  89.940002
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas sum every value over certain month range every year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60570666/pandas-sum-every-value-over-certain-month-range-every-year)

Comment: @wwii Here is my question.  I want to Compute semi-annual (six-monthly) returns by compounding monthly returns over six-monthly periods from May-October and November-April

Comment: That's a statement not a question. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. The Q&A in the link shows one way to perform calculations on a portion of time series data Often it is easier if you make the datetime column the index of the DataFrame. [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).